# Why does the regex not capture 'www.'

Tags: python, regex, url

I'm creating a simple (I thought it would be simple) regex expression to capture ulr information in groups. Everything lines up except when I use a web address that has 'www.'

Expression:

```
((https?):\/\/(?:www\.)?([\w\.\-\:]+)\/(.+))
```

Test URLs:

```
http://11.111.111.1:1010/nexus-2.3.1/service/local/artifact/maven/content?r=fake_release&g=com.fake&a=com.rake.fake.soap.webapp&v=LATEST&e=war
https://hello-ci.fake-re.com/jenkins/view/RAS/job/RAS_Designtime_Master/site/com.rake.fake.ras.documentation/kwl/Assessment-faker-gage.html
https://regex101.com/#python
https://www.google.com
http://www.apple.com
```

Why do I not get a match on `https://www.google.com` nor `http://www.apple.com`

Note: This regular expression is for a python application

Comment: FYI, you may want to use [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) rather than a regular expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those URLs are not matched because of the obligatory `/`. Make that part optional with a non-capturing group and `?` quantifier:

```
((https?):\/\/(?:www\.)?([\w\.\-\:]+)(?:\/(.+))?)
                                     ^^^      ^^
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dS5rG1/1)